# What is the value of this complex integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

$$\int_{C_2(0)}\frac{sin(z)}{z^2+1}\ dz$$

Where $C_2(0)$ is the open ball of radius 2, centred at 0, in the complex plane.

I have attempted this on my own (using Cauchy's integral formula and partial fractions) and consistently keep getting $-2i\pi  sinh(1)$.

**My workings**:

$$ \frac{1}{z^2+1} = \frac{i}{2(z+i)} -\frac{i}{2(z-i)}$$
$$\int_{C_2(0)}\frac{sin(z)}{z^2+1}\ dz = \int_{C_2(0)}\frac{isin(z)}{2(z+i)}\ dz-\int_{C_2(0)}\frac{isin(z)}{2(z-i)}\ dz $$

Using Cauchy's intgral formula:

$$f(-i) = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{C_2(0)}\frac{isin(z)}{2(z+i)}\ dz = -\frac{1}{2}sinh1 \Rightarrow \int_{C_2(0)}\frac{isin(z)}{2(z+i)} = -isinh(1)\pi$$

$$f(i) = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{C_2(0)}\frac{isin(z)}{2(z-i)}\ dz = \frac{1}{2}sinh1 \Rightarrow \int_{C_2(0)}\frac{isin(z)}{2(z-i)} = isinh(1)\pi$$

Hence:

$$\int_{C_2(0)}\frac{isin(z)}{2(z+i)}\ dz-\int_{C_2(0)}\frac{isin(z)}{2(z-i)}\ dz = - isinh(1)\pi - isinh(1)\pi = -2isinh(1)\pi $$

However, the actual solution given to me is $2i\pi  sinh(1)$.

Is the solution I was given wrong or am I wrong?

Edit: added workings

Comment: Is it the integral over the open ball, or around its boundary?

Comment: I think the official solution is correct. Can I suggest you edit your question to including your working, so that we can comment on your solution?

Comment: Is the integration path $|z|=2$ from $\arg(z)=0$ to $\arg(z)=2\pi$ (i.e., the circle of radius $2$, centered at $0$, and traversed counterclockwise)?  If so, your answer is off by a minus sign.

Comment: @KennyWong I put in an edit showing my workings

Comment: There is a sign error in your evaluate of $f(-i)$ (where $f(z) = i \sin z / 2)$: $f(-i) = i \sin (-i)/2 = i(i \sinh(-1))/2 = i(-i\sinh 1)/2 = + \frac 1 2 \sinh 1$.

Answer (score 5):

The sign of the answer will depend on the orientation of the path around $C_0(2)$. (Presumably you are computing a line integral around the ball.) Since the orientation is not prescribed in the problem, the answers are consistent.